# DataOutputStream only writes a string Java

Tags: java, output, outputstream

```
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt"));
dataOut.writeUTF("HEY");   // write HEY
dataOut.writeShort(1);     // writes nothing
```

I am trying to use DataOutputStream to write something in my text file. However, it only writes a string, not an integer or short. I do not understand why it only writes strings. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: Despite calling the file `myfile.txt`, this is a binary not a text format so you can't expect to read it as text e.g. with a text editor and see the short value.

This works fine if you close the file and read it the same way it was written.

```
try (DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt"))) {
    dataOut.writeUTF("HEY");   // write HEY
    dataOut.writeShort(1);
}
try (DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"))) {
    System.out.println("string: " + dataIn.readUTF());
    System.out.println("short: " + dataIn.readShort());
}
```

prints

```
string: HEY
short: 1
```

Most likely you expected the file to be text.

```
try (PrintWriter dataOut = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt"))) {
    dataOut.println("HEY");   // write HEY
    dataOut.println(1);
}
try (Scanner dataIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("myfile.txt"))) {
    System.out.println("string: " + dataIn.nextLine());
    System.out.println("short: " + dataIn.nextShort());
}
```

prints

```
string: HEY
short: 1
```

and the file contains

```
HEY
1
```

Comment: I'm surprised at you. `available()` does not return 'bytes left'. There are few correct uses of `available()`, and this isn't one of them.

Comment: @EJP from the JavaDoc of `available()`: *Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read*. Don't understand what Peter did wrong

Comment: @Lino Classic partial quotation. Have a look at the last two words in the sentence you just misquoted.

Comment: @EJP *(or skipped over)* -> skip and read can only be done over bytes that are left, or not?

Comment: @Lino You need to read, and quote, the entire sentence. Not just the bits you like.

Comment: @EJP It happens to work in this case, but could be used incorrectly in another context. Taking it out of this example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The Javadoc is perfectly clear. It happens to work but is still incorrect in *this* case. I did once find a correct use for it, but I've long fforgotten what it was.

Comment: @Lino For your assistance, and for avoidance of doubt, the part of it that you omitted says *'without blocking'.*

Comment: @EJP I understand, again, sorry for the confusion, brain is not working as it should

Answer (score 1):

You have produced no evidence for your assertion. Neither `writeUTF()` nor `writeInt()` produces text. They both produce binary data. You should not try to save this data in a file with the .txt extension (and you should not try to read it with a text editor). The only way you can read this data is with a `DataInputStream`.

Comment: @Lino 'Proper alternative' to what? Why does he need an alternative output stream? He wants to write strings and ints and shorts. He is. The problem is with how he is *reading* the file.

Comment: @Lino Where does it say he wants to read it with a text editor?

Comment: you're right, he never said that, sorry for the confusion